# call angluar2 method within the success method of the cordova camera plugin

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, android-camera

I've successfully integrated a cordova plugin within my angular2 project.
I call the "takePicture" method which succesfully calls the native camera.

```
public takePicture() {
    const srcType = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
    const options = this.setOptions(srcType);
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onSuccess, this.onFail,options);
  }

  public onSuccess(imageData) {
    this.capture('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData); <-- this doesn't work here I guess

  }

  public onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    console.log(message);
  }
.....
```

The problem is when I take a picture and I call the onSuccess function it will fail when I call this.capture(....) with the following error:

> core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of
>   null

which means angular doesn't know the method this.capture(..). 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Cannot read property 'capture' of **null**. I think you need to first check if there is any data popping in

Comment: I checke the imageData is filled.

Comment: If I debug I see that this is null in method. On compling I do not have an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the object context when passing instance methods as callbacks, therefore `this` evaluates to `null`.

You can easily fix it by wrapping the method call in a function:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    (data) => this.onSuccess(data),
    (message) => this.onFail(message),
    options
);
```